# How can I calculate the ROI of an investment from its cash flow?

Tags: investing

I've my company cash flow and I'd like to understand if my company is more or less profitable than lending money asking back a 6% yearly interest.

Where can I start from? Is there any Excel Formula?

Comment: fyi https://money.stackexchange.com/a/89671/11768

Comment: also https://money.stackexchange.com/a/64524/11768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ROI that can be calculated purely from cash flows is the [internal rate of return](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/irr-function-64925eaa-9988-495b-b290-3ad0c163c1bc).